# How to write more readable c++20 concepts?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm writing a template class that wraps a user-supplied class in an elaborate wrapper. I'm looking for a better way to enforce interface requirements for a target type using C++20 concepts.

(The precise application is a template class that simplifies marshalling of a co-await call onto a separate non-coroutine execution context and back again onto a coroutine thread of execution. Think asynchronous i/o wrappers if you must. Consider the non-trivial state machine required to do thread-safe asynchronous time-outs, completion callbacks, teardown, and dispatching back to the original coroutine thread of execution without leaking.)

```
template <typename T>
concept IoCoServiceImplementation = requires(
    T t,
    typename T::return_type x,
    CoServiceCallback<typename T::return_type> *callback)
{
    {t.Execute(callback)} -> std::same_as<void>;
    {t.Cancel(callback)} -> std::same_as<bool>;
};

template <IoCoServiceImplementation SERVICE_IMPLEMENTATION>
class CoServiceAwaitable {
      ...
 };
```

What I want concisely: `IoCoServiceImplementation` must provide two methods:

```
class AnImplementation {
public:
       using return_type = RETURN_TYPE;
       void Execute(CoServiceCallback<return_type>*);
       bool Cancel(CoServiceCallback<return_type>*);
 }
```

Note the significant difference in readability of the concept and the example. Also worth noting is that the generated error message doesn't supply the actual types required. You would have to browse the source of the concept declaration to figure out what callback means when you get `error blahblah requires {t.Execute(callback)}`.

While I can think of a dozen ways to hack a concept that requires the methods I want, none of them seem sufficiently readable and self-documenting. And the more I hack, the less readable the declarations, *and* error messages get.

I'm thinking about exploring whether `std::function<>` can be hacked to produce a readable and self-documenting declarations. Something like:

```
 { std::function< void T::Execute(CoServiceCallback<return_type>*)  > };
 { std::function< bool T::Cancel(CoServiceCallback<return_type>*)  > };
```

(which doesn't actually work, obvsly).

Is there a better way to do this? Has anyone delivered style guidelines for concepts yet?

--

Proactively, because I'm sure this will come up...

You could quibble about whether it should be `std::same_as<bool>` or `std::convertable_to<bool>`. Here's my thinking on that. I expect a bool. If that method returns anything other than bool, I can't imagine what it would it be. So it's reasonable to insist that it not be something I don't expect.

A frequent argument defending the deficiencies of the current C++ concept implementation: that concepts are supposed to enforce what you *can* do, not the precise implementation. In this case, I don't really care what you *can* do; I'm concerned with letting you know what you *do do*.

Comment: The concept is already as terse as it could be (at least to my eyes), except that `typename T::return_type x` is redundant. In your proposed syntax, you didn't specify template arguments for `CoServiceCallback`. If you did, it would look a lot less nice, and you'd naturally want to extract the repeating type somewhere (which is what `requires` does).

Comment: `typename T::return_type x,` exists to provide a better error if T:return_type hasn't been declared. (not something I like, but something that's neccessary)

Comment: @RobinDavies: "*I expect a bool.*" No, you expect something you can use in an `if` statement or somesuch. Something that you can *use* like a `bool`. Why do you *care* if it isn't a `bool`, so long as all of the code you expect to use it with works fine.

Comment: @RobinDavies: "*I'm concerned with letting you know what you do do.*" Why? That's not your job. Your job as the writer of a template using this concept is to use the given types in accord with the expressions you provided in the template. That's it. Your concept says what a user must provide in terms of legal expressions, and your code only uses those types with those expressions. How the user fulfills that concept is *not your concern*; let the user have their freedom.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: lol. I did expect this. If the user has something that's convertible to bool, then they can convert it to bool before they return. Given that I'm going to assign the result a bool anyway, I don't see how imprecision provides anything useful.

Comment: @RobinDavies: What "imprecision"? It's precision that you *should not* care about, and trying to control it is just being over-controlling of the user's interface. Templates and concepts are *supposed* to have this kind of variability in them. There is nothing to be gained by locking a user's decisions down to a specific signature. The only reason we lock `virtual` functions down that hard is that we don't really have a choice, implementation-wise, because the compiler cannot see the derived class function at the base class call site. With templates, it can.

Comment: @RobinDavies: Indeed, the whole point of duck typing is that you don't care about such trivial details. You don't want a thing that "is a duck"; you want a thing that "*acts* like a duck". It's not actually important to your "duck" that it takes a particular parameter and returns `void`; it's important that you can call it with a particular kind of argument.

Comment: Nicol Bolas: In my mind, the point of this particular exercise is to document a _contract_ between user and consumer. `bool result = IMPLEMENTATION.Cancel(callback)`. Now it's a duck.  You do you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two `requires` clauses, first determine whether `T` has a member type of `return_type`, which can be used to stop the concept check as early as possible

```
template<typename T>
concept IoCoServiceImplementation = 
  requires { typename T::return_type; } && 
  requires (
    T& t, CoServiceCallback<typename T::return_type>* callback) {
    { t.Execute(callback) } -> std::same_as<void>;
    { t.Cancel(callback)  } -> std::same_as<bool>;
  };
```

> I'm thinking about exploring whether std::function<> can be hacked to
> produce a readable and self-documenting declarations.

This is not a good idea, first of all, you need to include extra (and unnecessary) headers, and it's not as intuitive as compound requirements with *return-type-requirement*.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/09/18/cppcon-whiteboard-puzzle/ to me. The correct idiomatic answer is *don't do that.* Your existing concept is perfectly readable, and you can make it even more readable by dropping the `-> std::same_as<...>` suffixes that everyone in the comments is objecting to.

A long-standing trick to make templates more readable is to use defaulted template parameters as "poor man's type aliases," like this:

```
template<class T, class R = typename T::return_type>
concept IoCoServiceImplementation =
  requires (T t, R x, CoServiceCallback<R> *cb) {
    t.Execute(cb);
    t.Cancel(cb) ? true : false;
  };

template <IoCoServiceImplementation SERVICE_IMPLEMENTATION>
class CoServiceAwaitable {
  ...
};
```

Notice that we don't care what `t.Execute(cb)` returns, because we aren't going to use it. And we don't care *precisely* what type `t.Cancel(cb)` returns, as long as we can branch on it like a boolean.

Also notice that that particular `typename` keyword is optional in C++20; if you want to write `class R = T::return_type`, and your compiler accepts it, feel free.

Actually, your parameter `R x` is unused right now. Maybe I should have eliminated it, but I assumed you were going to use it in some other *simple-requirement* that you'd simply omitted for brevity.

Comment: The purpose of `T::return_type x` was to require a `T::return_type`. 康桓瑋 correctly points out that it should be written as  `requires { typename T::return_type; } &&...`

Comment: @RobinDavies: Sure, but in your example you had already enforced that via the `callback` parameter's type, and in my example I had already enforced that via the `R` template parameter's default. There's no particular reason to repeat `R x` in the requires-expression's parameter list. But yeah, if you are going to repeat it somewhere just for self-documentation, then `typename T::return_type;` as a _type-requirement_ inside the curly braces is the best place for it.

Comment: The requirement `t.Cancel(cb) ? true : false;` feels a bit hacky in my opinion. Is there any downside to using `static_cast<bool>(t.Cancel(cb));` instead?